What are the binary sequences found near crashed interceptors?
Broken robotic parts can be found near crashed interceptor ships or bases on corrupted worlds. Inspecting and interacting with them give you an integer number followed by a binary sequence.
Apparently, there are 11 of them, the binary sequence can be converted in a decimal number, which then translates to a letter in ASCII, giving this message:

VOID MOTHER

(with an unrelated(?) 17th code saying only "???").
Are they telling me something? Is there a sort of hidden mission, or is this just lore?

So far, the most reasonable answer is that the message is just a lore hook device that has no real consequences other than informing you about some plot elements (that is, assuming you know what it is referring to).
To put this in context, consider this:

no one has ever found the other missing pieces. Nor during an expedition, nor during normal gameplay. See how this effort ended, for example.I wasn't able to find any up-to-date text dump to check if other (unused?) string exist.
the existence of a 17th code is intriguing not just because some codes are missing. 17 is 16+1. So, in a way, 17 alludes to something past 16.
go to a space station in a Korvax system, try to feed some Atlantideum to the station core.

Unless you enjoy looking for out of place things, your best bet is to wait this out since probably the answer isn't in the game yet.
The plot of No Man Sky is weird. If you looked at the game at launch you would see only some basic element like a rough version of Artemis path and the final revelation. Then, update after update new plot devices were added in: the Adriane mess with the weekend quests, more and more references to the "Glass" and its nature, the "Water", the Admin....
Some feature of the game were changed. At launch, the players were separated. Then, a first form of multiplayer allowed them to see each other as little less than light balls, and then again another update added real co-op. Portals were just piece of stones without any logic (players even datamined the game and found they had no attached behavior or interactivity), then they were fixed and we got the ability to travel using addresses...
And at the same time, the game lore seems to reference itself. Travelers will tell you how the iterations were separated but now the boundaries are falling and allowing them to meet. Some will mention worlds "changing" that seems to allude to the procedural generation updates. Is "16" just slowly becoming the countdown to "Light no Fire"?
For each piece getting into shape the game continues to add something new that makes "no sense". You mentioned the incomplete Harmonic Scraps code, but have you ever heard about the "ANOMALOUS NUMBERS STATION" and the random addresses they seem to transmit?
The only "advice" I can give right now is to keep your eyes open. For a while the game has been hinting to two factions, and oddly enough the players had their part in choosing what path to walk. One recent expedition allowed the player to choose Atlas or Atlantid and while some tried to pursue both... some now have a weird visitor in the Anomaly, whose "unlock" conditions are not exactly clear. Last update added a similar choice to the Atlas path and now the Mark Of The Denier exists.
If you think about it, the game currently has two opposing "forces". It is (probably?) early to worry, but.. you may have to make a choice someday.

Notice: I didn't mention "those who returned" since technically it is a separated quest. Leave me a notice if you want that included

Ok that's enough for me, thanks! I may need to feed some Atlantideum to the Korvax station core, never tried that
